# How to position an SVG circle along another circle's path

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm building a Gauge chart in a presentational component in React.

I just need to pass it a percentage and let the component do the rest. I can't use any animations because I'm taking a screenshot of the component to place the image in a Powerpoint presentation.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

As you can see in my code snippet, the circle `<marker>` is being positioned at the end of the grey `<path>` instead of at the end of the green `<path>`. How could I position the circle so it sits at the `stroke-linecap` of the green `<path>` as in the image above?

Here's the HTML code I have so far:

```html
<div style="width:400px">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <marker
        id="dot"
        viewBox="0 0 10 10"
        refX="4"
        refY="4"
        markerWidth="4"
        markerHeight="4"
      >
        <circle
          cx="4"
          cy="4"
          r="2"
          fill="#FFFFFF"
          stroke="#008000"
          stroke-width="2"
        />
      </marker>
    </defs>
    <path d="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0" stroke="#D3D7DB" stroke-width="4" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
    <path d="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0" stroke="#008000" stroke-width="6" pathLength="100" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="75 35" marker-end="url(#dot)"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm on my phone, so just quick hint. If you put the small circle in <g> node and set the translate right, you can then wrap it in another which sets the rotation correctly. Still, you need some script to alter the rotation depending on the percentage.

Comment: A better way to do this would be to use a path with an arc command and a marker. Markers auto-orient by default, so if the marker is not a symmetric shape, you don't have to calculate your own rotation transform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it all in SVG by setting `pathLength` and using `animationMotion` to position the circle.

Some JavaScript and a W3C standard Web Component (JSWC supported in all modern Browsers) help in putting multiple gauges on screen and making them dynamic.

[image]

```js
customElements.define("svg-gauge", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    let speed = 0.5; // set to 0.0001 for instant display!
    let arc = "M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0";
    let col = this.getAttribute("color") || "green";
    this.innerHTML = 
    `<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="0"`+ // delete 2 lines
    ` oninput="this.parentNode.percent=this.value" /><br>`+ // just for demo
    `<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
       <path d="${arc}" stroke="grey" stroke-width="6" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
       <path id="P" d="${arc}" stroke="${col}" stroke-width="8" pathLength="100" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="75 35"/>
       <circle stroke="${col}" cx="0" cy="0" fill="#fff" r="4" stroke-width="3">
         <animateMotion dur="${speed}s" path="${arc}" keyPoints="0;0.75" fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear"/>
       </circle>
       <text x="50%" y="40%" text-anchor="middle">XXX</text>
     </svg>`;
    this.style.display='inline-block';
    this.percent = this.getAttribute("value") || "50";
  }
  set percent(val = 0) {
    this.setAttribute("value", val);
    let dash = val + " " + (105 - val);
    this.querySelector("#P").setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', dash);
    this.querySelector("animateMotion").setAttribute('keyPoints', '0;'+val/100);
    this.querySelector("text").innerHTML =`${val} %`;
    this.querySelector("animateMotion").beginElement();
    this.querySelector("input").value = val;
  }
})
```

```html
<svg-gauge value="35" color="red"   ></svg-gauge>
<svg-gauge value="50" color="orange"></svg-gauge>
<svg-gauge value="75" color="green" ></svg-gauge>
```

Comment: this is a very good answer, but i am wondering why a div and or/<img> tag does not work , does not show, but <circle tag> showing fine

Comment: Sure, you can also do it with HTML and CSS. Many roads lead to Rome [pun intended]

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and accepted Danny '365CSI' Engelman's answer above, but just in case anyone wants to do this without the animations here is how I ended up implementing it:

```html
<div style="width:400px">
  <svg viewBox="0 -10 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0" stroke="#D3D7DB" stroke-width="4" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
    <path d="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0" stroke="#008000" stroke-width="6" pathLength="100" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="50 85"></path>
    <circle
          cx="0"
          cy="0"
          r="6"
          stroke-width="6"
          fill="#FFFFFF"
          stroke="#008000"
        >
          <animateMotion
            begin="0s"
            dur="infinite"
            repeatCount="infinite"
            keyPoints="0.5;0.5"
            fill="freeze"
            keyTimes="0;1"
            calcMode="linear"
            path="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0"
          ></animateMotion>
        </circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```