# Div does not show while trying to animate it along an SVG path

Tags: html, svg, svg-animate

I am having a situation which is very very much like this one:
[How to position an SVG circle along another circle's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68041509/how-to-position-an-svg-circle-along-another-circles-path)
Actually it is almost identical, except I am not working with a  circle, I am working with a **div which contains an image**, but the div does not show at all, not even in the browser's inspector.

So referencing the same solution to the other question, this is what he got:

```html
<div style="width:400px">
  <svg viewBox="0 -10 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0" stroke="#D3D7DB" stroke-width="4" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
    <path d="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0" stroke="#008000" stroke-width="6" pathLength="100" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="50 85"></path>
    <circle
          cx="0"
          cy="0"
          r="6"
          stroke-width="6"
          fill="#FFFFFF"
          stroke="#008000"
        >
          <animateMotion
            begin="0s"
            dur="infinite"
            repeatCount="infinite"
            keyPoints="0.5;0.5"
            fill="freeze"
            keyTimes="0;1"
            calcMode="linear"
            path="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0"
          ></animateMotion>
        </circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

It works perfectly fine, now my situation is the same, except I am trying to have a a div and img instead of a circle, and although it should work in theory but it does not show the div:

```html
<div style="width:400px">
  <svg viewBox="0 -10 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0" stroke="#D3D7DB" stroke-width="4" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
    <path d="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0" stroke="#008000" stroke-width="6" pathLength="100" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="50 85"></path>
    <!-- make animateMotion a child of the div , no need to use xlink:href,
    just like it is done in the answer above -->
    
    <div>
         <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
          <animateMotion
            begin="0s"
            dur="infinite"
            repeatCount="infinite"
            keyPoints="0.5;0.5"
            fill="freeze"
            keyTimes="0;1"
            calcMode="linear"
            path="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0"
          ></animateMotion>
        </div>
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Or a better way by referencing the object ID:**

```html
<div style="width:400px">
  <svg viewBox="0 -10 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0" stroke="#D3D7DB" stroke-width="4" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
    <path d="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0" stroke="#008000" stroke-width="6" pathLength="100" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="50 85"></path>
    <div id="my-circle">
         <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
    </div>
    
    <!-- keep animateMotion out side of the div and use xlink:href-->
    
          <animateMotion
          xlink:href="#my-circle"
            begin="0s"
            dur="infinite"
            repeatCount="infinite"
            keyPoints="0.5;0.5"
            fill="freeze"
            keyTimes="0;1"
            calcMode="linear"
            path="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0"
          ></animateMotion>
        
  </svg>
</div>
```

However you can see in both cases, the div is not showing, any reason for this?

Thank you

Comment: Html in svg must be within a foreignObject element

Comment: svg html inside the div you mean? how is that possible? can you demonstrate?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

Comment: thanks, that actually works for Chrome and Firefox but not Safari