# Creating a Circular SVG Temperature Dragger in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, svg

This is a static demo of the circular thumb dragger I'm trying to create in Angular.  It uses the `stroke-dashoffset="-260"` setting to position the thumb /dragger close to the end of the circular path behind the thumb, and as can be seen the `-260` negative offset works as expected.

```html
    <body style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
    <svg
      (mousedown)="onMouseDown($event)"
      #svgRoot
      id="svgclick"
      version="1.1"
      viewBox="0 0 79.375 79.375"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        transform="rotate(90)"
        d="m64.961-15.355a34.984 34.412 0 0 1-49.474 1e-6 34.984 34.412 0 0 1-1e-6 -48.666 34.984 34.412 0 0 1 49.474-2e-6"
        fill="none"
        stroke="#000"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke-width="10.583"
      />
      <path
        #thumb
        transform="rotate(90)"
        d="m64.961-15.355a34.984 34.412 0 0 1-49.474 1e-6 34.984 34.412 0 0 1-1e-6 -48.666 34.984 34.412 0 0 1 49.474-2e-6"
        fill="none"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke="#F66"
        stroke-width="18"
        pathlength="270"
        stroke-dasharray="0 270"
        stroke-dashoffset="-260"
        id="thumb"
      />
    </svg>
  </body>
```

When I use the same code in this Angular Stackblitz the `stroke-dashoffset="-260"` does not work the same way.

This is a live dragger demo.  If you try to drag the thumb, the drag "Accelerates" and pushes the thumb further and further out.  Note that the value corresponding to the offset calculation and the number of degrees that the click or drag represents is logged.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptzvsm?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Any ideas on why it's doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to position an SVG circle along another circle's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68041509/how-to-position-an-svg-circle-along-another-circles-path)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman that looks promising and I tried it out and ended up with another question ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75463543/positioning-an-svg-circle-on-top-of-a-circular-path-using-keypoints

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the circular thumb dragger in the provided Angular Stackblitz is caused by an incorrect calculation for the stroke-dashoffset value. To fix this, you can use the stroke-dasharray value to determine the length of the circular path and update the stroke-dashoffset based on the distance the thumb has moved around the circle

Comment: Hi @Oai.  Welcome to SO!  So there are 270 degrees around the SVG path that is represented as the background.  So when drag or click occurs I calculate the number of degrees that the click represents and us that to set the negative offset.  And it the static demo it looks like it works fine, but in the Angular demo the result is not the same.  For example if the offset is set to `-260` in the static demo the thumb goes to the end of the circle, however if the same is done in the Angular demo, the result is different.  Any ideas why?

Comment: the issue with the circular thumb dragger in the Angular demo is related to the way the stroke-dashoffset value is being calculated.
In the static demo, the stroke-dashoffset value of -260 is used to position the thumb at the end of the circular path behind the thumb. However, in the Angular demo, the stroke-dashoffset value is being calculated based on the angle of the click event, which doesn't account for the length of the path or the length of the thumb. This causes the thumb to "accelerate" as it is dragged around the circle, since stroke-dashoffset value is not being updated correctly.

Comment: To fix this, you can use the getTotalLength() method to get the length of the thumb path, and calculate the stroke-dashoffset value based on the distance the thumb has moved around the circle.

Comment: I've set the length of the thumb path to 270 using the `pathlength` attribute.  Should the offset just set the thumb to the correct location based on the `configured` length?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The stroke-dashoffset attribute sets the starting position of the dash pattern along the path. In this case, the dash pattern is the stroke of the thumb path, and the path it follows is the same as the path element in the background.

Comment: By setting the pathlength attribute of the thumb path to 270, you're essentially saying that the length of the thumb path is equal to the circumference of the circular path in the background. Then, setting stroke-dashoffset to a negative value (e.g. -260) moves the starting point of the dash pattern (the thumb) along the path by 260 units, which corresponds to 260/270 = 0.963 or about 96.3% of the total circumference of the path.

Comment: So, when the thumb element is drawn, it will start 96.3% of the way around the path, near the end of the circular path. As the user drags the thumb element, the stroke-dashoffset is updated to reflect the new position of the thumb element along the path, allowing the element to be dragged along the circular pa

Comment: Oai ... So we are thinking the same way ... I think ... :) ... And to me it seems like it should work ... but it's not working ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).