# Positioning an SVG Circle on top of a circular path using keypoints?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68041509/how-to-position-an-svg-circle-along-another-circles-path) the author of the question is able to position an SVG circle on top of a path like this:

```html
<div style="width:400px">
  <svg viewBox="0 -10 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0" stroke="#D3D7DB" stroke-width="4" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
    <path d="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0" stroke="#008000" stroke-width="6" pathLength="100" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="50 85"></path>
    <circle
          cx="0"
          cy="0"
          r="6"
          stroke-width="6"
          fill="#FFFFFF"
          stroke="#008000"
        >
          <animateMotion
            begin="0s"
            dur="infinite"
            repeatCount="infinite"
            keyPoints="0.5;0.5"
            fill="freeze"
            keyTimes="0;1"
            calcMode="linear"
            path="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0"
          ></animateMotion>
        </circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I've noticed that if I change the first `keyPoints` value it moves the circle.  This is a [stackblitz containing the same markup in case anyone wants to play with it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-fw6cnh?file=index.html,styles.css).

I'd like to apply this approach to a different path.

```
      <path
        #thumb
        transform="rotate(90)"
        d="m64.961-15.355a34.984 34.412 0 0 1-49.474 1e-6 34.984 34.412 0 0 1-1e-6 -48.666 34.984 34.412 0 0 1 49.474-2e-6"
        fill="none"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke="#F66"
        stroke-width="18"
        pathlength="270"
        stroke-dasharray="0 270"
        stroke-dashoffset="-260"
        id="thumb"
      />
```

And I assumed it would just be a matter of copying in the circle markup:

```
        <circle
              cx="0"
              cy="0"
              r="6"
              stroke-width="6"
              fill="#FFFFFF"
              stroke="#008000"
            >
              <animateMotion
                begin="0s"
                dur="infinite"
                repeatCount="infinite"
                keyPoints="0.5;0.5"
                fill="freeze"
                keyTimes="0;1"
                calcMode="linear"
                path="M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0"
              ></animateMotion>
            </circle>
```

And then changing the `path` attribute value from `M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0` to `m64.961-15.355a34.984 34.412 0 0 1-49.474 1e-6 34.984 34.412 0 0 1-1e-6 -48.666 34.984 34.412 0 0 1 49.474-2e-6`, however this ends up placing the circle on top of the SVG path and almost out of focus.

```html
 <body>
    <svg
      #svgRoot
      id="svgclick"
      version="1.1"
      viewBox="0 0 79.375 79.375"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        transform="rotate(90)"
        d="m64.961-15.355a34.984 34.412 0 0 1-49.474 1e-6 34.984 34.412 0 0 1-1e-6 -48.666 34.984 34.412 0 0 1 49.474-2e-6"
        fill="none"
        stroke="#000"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke-width="10.583"
      />
      <path
        #thumb
        transform="rotate(90)"
        d="m64.961-15.355a34.984 34.412 0 0 1-49.474 1e-6 34.984 34.412 0 0 1-1e-6 -48.666 34.984 34.412 0 0 1 49.474-2e-6"
        fill="none"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke="#F66"
        stroke-width="18"
        pathlength="270"
        stroke-dasharray="0 270"
        stroke-dashoffset="-260"
        id="thumb"
      />
      <circle
        cx="0"
        cy="0"
        r="6"
        stroke-width="6"
        fill="#FFFFFF"
        stroke="#008000"
      >
        <animateMotion
          begin="0s"
          dur="infinite"
          repeatCount="infinite"
          keyPoints="0.1;0.5"
          fill="freeze"
          keyTimes="0;1"
          calcMode="linear"
          path="m64.961-15.355a34.984 34.412 0 0 1-49.474 1e-6 34.984 34.412 0 0 1-1e-6 -48.666 34.984 34.412 0 0 1 49.474-2e-6"
        ></animateMotion>
      </circle>
    </svg>
  </body>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `transform` attribute is quite simply not applied to the motion path. Wrap the paths and the circle in a `<g transform="rotate(90)">`, remove the attributes from the individual paths, and all vectors will be positioned collectively.
   Applying that transform attribute to the `<circle>` element will not work. That would only rotate the circle in place around its center. The motion path would be applied in the un-rotated coordinate system.
2. You should take the time to understand how the `<animateMotion>` works. It animates the circle, moving it from the first value of `keyPoints` to the second during the duration of the animation. The attribute `dur` has the value `infinite`, which is simply invalid. Instead, the initial value `indefinite` is used. Since there is also no `end` value, interpolation of values is turned off, you see no motion, and the first value is used at all times. That is what you intended, but I would think it preferable to stay with a valid combination of values and set *both* values of `keyPoints` to the same.
3. Currently, your `stroke-dasharray="0 270"` draws a zero-length dash (visible as a circle because of `stroke-linecap="round"`) and a gap of the path length. I suspect you intended to draw a partial path instead from the start of the path to the dot position. For that use: `stroke-dasharray="270 270"`.
   Also, `stroke-dashoffset="-260"` and `keyPoints="0.1;0.1"` do not match. While the keyPoints go from 0...1, the dashoffset has to move from 270...0. So the correct value for the offset is 270 * (1 - 0.1) = 243.

```html
<body>
    <svg
      #svgRoot
      id="svgclick"
      version="1.1"
      viewBox="0 0 79.375 79.375"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <g transform="rotate(90)" >
        <path
          d="m64.961-15.355a34.984 34.412 0 0 1-49.474 1e-6 34.984 34.412 0 0 1-1e-6 -48.666 34.984 34.412 0 0 1 49.474-2e-6"
          fill="none"
          stroke="#000"
          stroke-linecap="round"
          stroke-linejoin="round"
          stroke-width="10.583"
        />
        <path
          #thumb
          d="m64.961-15.355a34.984 34.412 0 0 1-49.474 1e-6 34.984 34.412 0 0 1-1e-6 -48.666 34.984 34.412 0 0 1 49.474-2e-6"
          fill="none"
          stroke-linecap="round"
          stroke-linejoin="round"
          stroke="#F66"
          stroke-width="18"
          pathlength="270"
          stroke-dasharray="270 270"
          stroke-dashoffset="243"
          id="thumb"
        />
        <circle
          cx="0"
          cy="0"
          r="6"
          stroke-width="6"
          fill="#FFFFFF"
          stroke="#008000"
        >
          <animateMotion
            begin="0s"
            dur="0s"
            repeatCount="infinite"
            keyPoints="0.1;0.1"
            fill="freeze"
            keyTimes="0;1"
            calcMode="linear"
            path="m64.961-15.355a34.984 34.412 0 0 1-49.474 1e-6 34.984 34.412 0 0 1-1e-6 -48.666 34.984 34.412 0 0 1 49.474-2e-6"
          ></animateMotion>
        </circle>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
```

Comment: Wow!!  Excellent answer!  I suspect some of you hints are going to clear up an earlier question I had as well.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Your new `<path>` is placed: x: 64.961 y:-15.355 (first 2 values after `m`)

That't why you path is almost off-canvas.
Since your path is already relative, you only need to change these 2 values to change the x/y offset in your viewBox.

You can also rotate the path `d` directly using [svg path editor.](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/)

```css
svg{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:20em;
  overflow:visible
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <path id="circlePath" d="M25.67 79.86a34.98 34.41 90 0 1 0-49.47a34.98 34.41 90 0 1 48.67 0a34.98 34.41 90 0 1 0 49.47" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" pathLength="100" />
  </defs>
  <use href="#circlePath" stroke="#D3D7DB" stroke-width="4" />
  <use href="#circlePath" stroke="#008000" stroke-width="6" stroke-dasharray="50 100" />
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="6" stroke-width="6" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#008000">
    <animateMotion fill="freeze" begin="0s" dur="0s" repeatCount="0" keyPoints="0.5;0.5"  keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear">
      <mpath xlink:href="#circlePath" />
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

You could also define your horseshoe path as a reusable element within `<def>` an reference it via `<use>` and `<mpath>`.