# Moving a circle programmatically using animateMotion after initial SVG rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg-animate

In this demo a circle is rendered using `animateMotion` and I need to be able to update the position of the circle after the initial rendering depending on where the user clicks.

```html
    <svg
      #svgRoot
      id="svgRoot"
      viewBox="0 0 100 100"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <defs>
        <path
          id="circlePath"
          d="M25.67 79.86a34.98 34.41 90 0 1 0-49.47a34.98 34.41 90 0 1 48.67 0a34.98 34.41 90 0 1 0 49.47"
          fill="none"
          stroke-linecap="round"
          pathLength="270"
        />
      </defs>
      <use id="track" href="#circlePath" stroke="#D3D7DB" stroke-width="8" />
      <use
        id="progress"
        href="#circlePath"
        stroke="#008000"
        stroke-width="10"
        stroke-dasharray="60 270"
      />
      <circle
        cx="0"
        cy="0"
        r="6"
        stroke-width="5"
        fill="#FFFFFF"
        stroke="#008000"
      >
        <animateMotion
          id="thumb"
          fill="freeze"
          begin="0s"
          dur="0s"
          repeatCount="0"
          keyPoints="0.6;0.6"
          keyTimes="0;1"
          calcMode="linear"
        >
          <mpath xlink:href="#circlePath" />
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
    </svg>
```

[Also this is a Stackblitz for experimentation.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-rayy38?file=index.html)

I thought that assigning a the new value to `keyPoints` within `animateMotion` would update the position of the circles, but when I play around with it developer tooling the changes don't change the rendering.

How do we update the position of the circle programmatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to position an SVG circle along another circle's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68041509/how-to-position-an-svg-circle-along-another-circles-path)

Comment: That's an excellent question and answer.  That's what I used to position the circle initially.  I needed to call `beginElement()` after changing the position configuration on the element, in order to get it repositioned.

Answer (score 0):

[OK after looking at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68041509/how-to-position-an-svg-circle-along-another-circles-path) I realized that we have to call `beginElement()` on the `animateMotion` element after making changes to the attributes.

Calling `beginElement()` moves the circle to the new position.

Comment: That's the answer I gave you yesterday...Now the only challenge is your click..

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman yes indeed :)!  Thanks Man!!  Gotta read the fine details :).